# Laravel redirect route and response json

Tags: php, json, laravel, return, laravel-5.1

How can I return a redirect routes with inputs etc. with a json response using laravel 5.1.

My current return looks like this:

```
return redirect()->route('root')->with('message', 'Success')->withInput();
```

and here is a sample json response from the docs:

```
return response()->json(['name' => 'Abigail', 'state' => 'CA']);
```

But I do not know how to put them together so to say.

Answer (score -1):

Can you try like this ?

```
return redirect()->route('root',array('name' => 'Abigail', 'state' => 'CA'))->with('message', 'Success')->withInput();
```

Answer (score -2):

Keep 2 routes. Place redirect from the first route to the second, which returns JSON.

You can not return any data from a redirect route. You can only put something to the user's session, which is what `->with(...)` does.